# how to make a HTML file path to go into a different folder for a css stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I have folders laid out like this

```
website main folder
  css
    style.css
  html
    index.html
```

I was wondering how to do a `<link>` tag to go to the CSS folder from index and link to style.css If you have a solution for this, please let me know.

thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Answer (score 0):

for this, you can use the HTML link tag,

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">`

sample :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDoeP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

or post you html code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link tag in head tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./../css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in HTML file

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../CSS/style.css>
```

this seems to work, it is just my IDE that docent accept this, but when I load it in my browser it is fine, thanks so much!